# How can I prevent multiple includes of the same view by developing component views with Laravel Blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a blog that shows 25 posts on the home page. Each post is displayed as a "block", with a dedicated "component" view being included 25 times. In this view there are 5 more inclusions (partials) leading to a total of **125 filesystem calls**. I don't like this.

Code to understand better:

```
// home.blade.php
@foreach($posts as $post)
    @include('components.post', ['post' => $post])
@endforeach


// components/post.blade.php
<div class="card">
    @include('components.post.partials.category')
    @include('components.post.partials.header')
    @include('components.post.partials.content')
    @include('components.post.partials.tags')
    @include('components.post.partials.share')
</div>
```

What is the best practice for handling this situation? I was not been able to find information about it although it is a common operation...

Comment: Consider sharing **all** of `components/post.blade.php` content.

Comment: I'm developing "components" without using Blade Components so I don't have a class, it's just @include like the example. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: noted. Could you share all the contents of `components/post.blade.php` file ?

Comment: so basically what you need is to only include those partials views only **1 time** ?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary. There is nothing particular or not working in these views. The problem is too many filesystem calls

Comment: I would like to include (filesystem call) once and reuse the components multiple times

Comment: I don't think you can do that. The `Blade` files are meant to be compiled each time in order to show the different data you send. If you think those partials are always the same (not dynamic) you may render them once, store in a variable, then reuse.

Comment: @ths FYI, now Laravel support caching of Component Views, more info here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/44487#issue-1399421217